# Jquery $('input[name=""]').change(function WILL NOT FIRE in Chrome unless there is an uncaught error after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

So, here's a script that I've written to make some inputs dependent on an affirmative answer from another input.  In this case, the 'parent' input is a radio button.

You can see that it hides parent divs of inputs when the document is ready, and then waits for the pertinent option to be changed before firing the logic.

If you'll look at the comment near the bottom of the javascript, you'll see what's been stumping me.  If I remove the if statement, the change function does not fire.  If I set the variable so that there is not an error logged in the console, then the change event does not fire.

If I change the jquery selector to `$('select').change...` the event fires, but obviously won't work on a radio button.  Changing it to `$('input').change...` also fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
                $(function(ready){
                    $('#input-option247').parent().hide();
                    $('#input-option248').parent().hide();
                    $('#input-option249').parent().hide();
                    $('#input-option250').parent().hide();
                    $('#input-quantity').attr('type', 'hidden');
                    $('#input-quantity').parent().hide();
                    $('input[name="option\\[230\\]"]').change(function() {
                        if (this.value == '21') { //If yes, display dependent options
                            $('#input-option247').parent().show().addClass('required');
                            $('#input-option248').parent().show().addClass('required');
                            $('#input-option249').parent().show().addClass('required');
                            $('#input-option250').parent().show().addClass('required');
                        } else if (this.value == '22') { //If no, hide dependent options
                            $('#input-option247').parent().hide().removeClass('required');
                            $('#input-option248').parent().hide().removeClass('required');
                            $('#input-option249').parent().hide().removeClass('required');
                            $('#input-option250').parent().hide().removeClass('required');
                        }
                    });
                    //I don't know why this is necessary, but the input.change() event WILL NOT FIRE unless it's present.  If I set the variable, then it breaks the change function above.  If it's not here, it breaks the change function above.  I'm stumped.
                    if(poop){}

                });//--></script>
```

I'm really hoping that someone will see something rather obvious that my tired brain won't see.  This is such a simple script, and I'm pulling my hair out over what seems like a rather annoying bug.

Comment: tl; dr; wouldn't convey the point that this is not how you should ask a question, and I can guarantee you that most people don't bother reading such questions. There are good reasons for that, and they're listed in the help section. That fact that someone was generous enough to sift through your code is encouraging, and I'm happy you have your solution, but my opinion stands that you shouldn't post such questions to begin with.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the question to remove the unnecessary HTML code so that nobody has to sift through it.  And unfortunately, I have no solution. I'm adding some additional details that will hopefully help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you selector has special characters you need to use `\\` before those characters.

`$('input[name="option[230]"]')`

should be

`$('input[name="option\\[230\\]"]')`

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you for that.  I've added the escape characters, and the event still will not fire without the if statement causing an uncaught reference error.

Comment: Also, I provided feedback on the answer, but my rep is too low to change the score.  Thank you for the useful feedback.

Comment: I find it peculiar that an error will cause your code to work correctly. I see your handler only does something when `this.value` is either 21 or 22. Possibly the value is something else, causing nothing to happen. Can you also check that `$('input[name="option\\[230\\]"]')` returns the element you are looking for?

Comment: When I send that to the console, it does indeed return the correct element and value.

Comment: The values `21` and `22` refer to Yes and No, respectively.  The input value is assigned programmatically by the CMS that I'm using, and don't have any bearing on the actual option presented to the user, apart from the links in the database. The HTML for the input is formatted like this: `<div id="input-option230">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="option[230]" value="21"> Yes</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="option[230]" value="22"> No</label>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: This is the best answer, although it turned out that another script was conflicting for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be a good answer, but I managed to get the problem solved.  I have another script on the page that is firing on the change event using this selector: `$('select[name^="option"], input[name^="option"]').change(function() {`

My best guess is that both functions cannot fire using a single change event from the same element.  I moved the functional part of the code above to be within the second script, and it seems to be working as expected.  If anyone wishes to contribute an answer that explains this behavior, I will accept it.